# How does the Enchanted Fountain work?

Tags: tiny-monsters

After the 1.2 update, a new decoration called the Enchanted Fountain is available. This item says that it gives you free diamonds. So how does it work?  How many diamonds will it give me and at what rate?  Is there any limit to how many fountains I can purchase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enchanted fountain to costs 100 diamonds it's supposed to give 1 diamond a day for 180days and you were supposed to be able to have a maximum of 9 so I bought 1 it's been working for a few days but I cant work out how to buy more